# PIC 18f and PORT-B

Tags: configuration, pic

Trying to get a 4x4 keypad working with a PIC 18f4685.

I've turned on weak-pulls ups.  Set the appropriate pins to either input/output but when I send a signal out I'm not getting it back on bits 6 & 7.  It just gets zeros...

I've tried to debug using the PicKit3 but seems that it uses RB7 and crashes things when a button for that row is pushed.  Of course that tells me that the signals must be getting through, to a point.

Is there anything else in particular that I need to set up in configuration for PORT B?

As always...your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which pins are inputs and which are outputs?  Assuming RB4-7 are inputs...

Comment: Thank you all for the additional ideas of possible config issues to look out for.  I managed to get it running.  Ya, can't use PicKit3 during debug testing and one of my solder joints was bad.  You're the best forum!  ALWAYS get a fast friendly responce!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the EE site so rudely shut you down before you could get an answer, I figured I would come here to answer your question.

Check table 10-3 on page 135, it lists all capabilities of port B pins.  Note that RB6 and RB7 are also the debugging pins, so I wouldn't use these.

Also, are you writing to LATx and reading from PORTx?  It's important to do this when reading and writing to the same port.  If you read and write to PORTx, you can accidentally read a stale value from an output that has not had enough time to change yet, and your next write will obliterate your intended value.  This is particularly pernicious on PICs that don't have a LATx register; any operation, even bit-wise operations like BSF/BCF, will do a read-modify-write of the ENTIRE port register, affecting more than the bit that you intended to modify.  See the answer to this EE question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28744/interfacing-a-keypad-with-a-microcontroller

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of exactly your schematic (a sketch might help) but a common error in PIC GPIO is not setting the ADC registers to digital inputs.  They come out of reset as analog inputs.

Look at register description 19-2 in the [PIC18F4685 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39761c.pdf).

`ADCON1` comes out of reset as 0x00.  To set all the analog pins to digital I/O, `PCFG3:0` need to be set to 1.

```
ADCON1bits.PCFG = 0x0F;
```

Comment: I would answear with that to @Adam as it is a common mistake :) +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks...I'll double check that.  However I'm thinking it might in fact be a hardware issue...poor solder joint.  Going to re-flow and also check the ADCON1 reg for proper set-up.

Comment: You can also set the Configuration bit PBADEN to avoid having to set ADCON1.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show use your code for setting the tristate registers (TRISB) and how you are reading. Have you checked the voltages at the input pins with a digital multimeter (DMM) before and during the button press? They are $10 and worth it.

Finally, did you disable the analog pins? On PIC24 chips you have to do:

`AD1PCFG = 0xFFFF`

before digital input reads will work. Might be the same on your chip.

Can you give us the EXACT model number of your chip?